# Database Relationships: not using the PK?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Say I had the following tables:

```
Foo
 - id
 - code (Unique)
 - name
 - descption

Bar
 - id
 - foo_code
```

Is there a disadvantage with `Bar.foo_code` pointing to `Foo.code`? Generally, I see the ids being referenced instead (e.g. there would be a `Bar.foo_id` that points to `Foo.id`), but in my case, it would be a lot simpler if it actually pointed to something other than the auto-incrementing PK.

I'm curious if this is bad design or if there will be a penalty in performance somehow.

Comment: Not really. As long as code doesn't change, it's fine. Celko would argue that your way is better ;-)

Comment: If you actually define the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, MySQL will _require_ that the column be indexed in the referenced table (or the FK will error) so it will be performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no disadvantages. Maybe on readability, depending on the real names of the columns. However, note that, if Foo.code is unique, then it is virtually a primary key. Just make sure it is also indexed and you are golden. If Foo.code is in fact unique, then you could even get rid of Foo.id and save some space.

Comment: I do think that `Foo.id` will be useless in my case, so maybe safe to delete.

Comment: Just check your data dictionary. If there are no references to it then it is safe to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

What reason do you have to keep the auto incrementing `id` around if really you're using another key as the primary key instead?

By default, a table would be sorted on the primary key. It may make more sense to have it sorted by `code` by default. Also, it'll take a bit more data storage, and updates get a bit slower as both indexes have to be updated. For many applications the performance difference will make very little practical difference, but I just can't think of a reason to keep the auto increment id around if you're not using it.

Surrogate primary keys do have their uses, but if you already have a unique column that you want to use as the primary key instead then using that unique column as your PK instead isn't bad design at all.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you intend to query:

- If you often need to determine the `code` associated with given `Bar`, then referencing it directly in the FK effectively **migrates** it from `Foo` to `Bar`, allowing you to do it **without** a JOIN.
- However, if you also need to fetch `Foo.name` or `Foo.descption`, then the JOIN is inevitable, and referencing `Foo.id` allows you avoid paying the **double-lookup** price [caused by the MySQL/InnoDB clustering](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/).

That being said, you may be able to [remove the surrogate key](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info) `Foo.id`, removing the entire dilemma.